# Running train-test split and obtaining model accuracies for different datasets

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I want to run train_test_split from sklearn package, using the same target variable y, but three different dataframes of independent variables. Then, I want to fit and predict using a Random Forest Classifier and get the accuracy. The goal here is to get accuracies for the three different dataframes so that I can compare them and select my variables accordingly. 
I have the following so far, which is not working.

```
df = [X1, X2, X3]   # 3 different independent variable (features) DataFrames. 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RandomForest
from sklearn import metrics
rf_accuracy = []

for index, z in enumerate(df):
  train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(z, y,train_size=0.5,test_size=0.5, random_state=2)
  rf = RandomForest(random_state=99)
  rf.fit(train_X, train_y.ravel())
  pred_y = rf.predict(test_X)
  rf_accuracy = rf_accuracy.append(metrics.accuracy_score(test_y, pred_y))

print(rf_accuracy)
```

When I print the rf_accuracy, I should get a list with three accuracies from using three different feature spaces `X1, X2, X3`, respectively.

For example, `rf_accuracy` will output [0.9765, 0.9645, 0.9212]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your data are like this

```py
assert df.shape == (n_samples, 3)   # each column for a variable/features
assert y.shape == (n_samples, )
```

and you are trying to train three RF clfs on the three different variables/features respectively.

Now, you can try this

```py
for _, z in df.iteritems():
  train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(
z.values.reshape(-1, 1), y, train_size=0.5, test_size=0.5, random_state=2)
  rf = RandomForest(random_state=99)
  rf.fit(train_X, train_y.ravel())
  pred_y = rf.predict(test_X)
  rf_accuracy = rf_accuracy.append(metrics.accuracy_score(test_y, pred_y))

print(rf_accuracy)
```

I succeeded in working on the iris dataset.

New:
[my modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPHZo.png)

Comment: this is great, but X1, X2, and X3 are 3 separate DataFrames themselves, not 3 columns in one dataframe. I want X1 (with 10 columns) to be used in train_test_split as the first parameter, then X2 (with 5 different columns), then X3 (with 7 column variables)

Comment: the sklearn train test runs as: train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(
X, y, train_size=0.5, test_size=0.5, random_state=2). I want to use 3 different dataframes and put them as 'X' in a loop

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I added a link (my modification) in the answer. I hope this will help you.